# Ruby Hash bug help!

Tags: ruby, string, hash, integer, typeerror

I'm trying to create a Ruby Hash of objects, where the keys are the object @name member:

```
# m is an object with an @name instance variable (a string)
myHash = {}
myHash[m.name] = m
```

It's giving this error:

```
#<TypeError: can't convert String into Integer>
```

Anyone know why? I'm sure that m.name is a valid string...

Comment: What happens when you call m.name on a line by itself?

Comment: To be very sure, use `p m.name.class`, but I suppose, anyway problem is somewhere else... Don't you have any other lines of code between that two your pasted here?

Comment: And preferably add the declaration of `m.name` to the code above.

Comment: Actually the error message agrees with you that m.name is a string. It's saying it wants an integer. Which would make me think that the myHash is an array, except you defined it as a hash on the line before (unless the real code is actually more complicated than that)... A runnable code sample that exhibits the problem would be nice.

Comment: Ah thank you sepp2k for turning me on to that... I realized I was accidentally reusing a variable name for the hash that was an array... doh! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was accidentally reusing a variable name that was an array... oops!

For some reason I thought the hash was tricking me because I hadn't used one in Ruby before...

Answer (score 0):

Does this irb example help?

```
> class MyClass
>   attr_reader :name
>   def initialize
>     @name = "myname"
>   end
> end
=> nil
> m = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x47c3e0 @name="myname">
> puts m.name
myname
=> nil
> myHash = {}
=> {}
> myHash[m.name] = m
=> #<MyClass:0x47c3e0 @name="myname">
> puts myHash.inspect
{"myname"=>#<MyClass:0x47c3e0 @name="myname">}
=> nil
```

notice the `attr_reader :name` which creates a getter method for name.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I had an attr_accessor